# CSS get 100% from div and not whole page

Tags: css, height

I'm trying to calculate something with calc in CSS. After hours I figured out that my actual div gives wrong 100% number.

Here is a small example:

```css
html, body, .calender {
 position: relative;
 height: 100%;
 overflow: hidden;
}

.appointmentsA {
 background: blue;
}

.appointmentsB {
 background: red;
}

.calender {
 display: table;
 width: 100%;
 table-layout: fixed;
 padding: 10px 10px 0 10px;
}
.calender .row {
 display: table-cell;
 padding: 0 10px;
}

.appointments {
 height: 100%;
}

.appointments:before {
   content: "test";
   position: absolute;
   top: calc(100% - 18px);
   color: #fff;
  }
```

```html
<main class="calender">
 <div class="row">
  <h1 class="title">ABC</h1>
  <div class="appointments appointmentsA"></div>
 </div>
 <div class="row">
  <h1 class="title">DEF</h1>
  <div class="appointments appointmentsB"></div>
 </div>
</main>
```

The red and blue blocks have a the same height as the container `row` and the main parent.

Is there a none javascript way to get the 100% height of the colored blocks?
If the colored block has the real 100%, then the ":after" element would show correctly and not just the half text.

Image: [example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n0u2x.jpg)

Comment: What do you mean for "to get the 100% height of the colored blocks"?

Comment: If you run the example and inspect it with the developer tools, then you can see the calculated height. It shows the same height at the "appointments" block as the e.g. the "row" block (with the title)

Comment: I still don't undestand sorry

Comment: Where are you using `calc`?

Comment: the two blocks don't have the same height of the row block in my inspector... but maybe it' easier if you say us what you are trying to achieve...

Comment: I added a small image, I will make another example what I try to do in a few minutes

Comment: image link doesn't work

Comment: uploaded somewhere else

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean to set color for full height col? If it is, set `position: absolute` for title:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html,
body,
.calender {
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.appointmentsA {
  background: blue;
}

.appointmentsB {
  background: red;
}

.calender {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  table-layout: fixed;
  padding: 10px 10px 0 10px;
}

.calender .row {
  display: table-cell;
  padding: 0 10px;
}

.appointments {
  height: 100%;
}

.title {
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<main class="calender">
  <div class="row">
    <h1 class="title">ABC</h1>
    <div class="appointments appointmentsA"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <h1 class="title">DEF</h1>
    <div class="appointments appointmentsB"></div>
  </div>
</main>
```

Or for colored div:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html,
body,
.calender {
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.appointmentsA {
  background: blue;
}

.appointmentsB {
  background: red;
}

.calender {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  table-layout: fixed;
  padding: 10px 10px 0 10px;
}

.calender .row {
  display: table-cell;
  padding: 0 10px;
  position: relative;
}

.appointments {
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}

.title {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
}
```

```html
<main class="calender">
  <div class="row">
    <h1 class="title">ABC</h1>
    <div class="appointments appointmentsA"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <h1 class="title">DEF</h1>
    <div class="appointments appointmentsB"></div>
  </div>
</main>
```

Comment: I don't want to color everything, I changed my example with the calc function.

Comment: Show what you want to get with an image, it is hard to understand what do you want

Answer (score 0):

I hope I've understood you correctly.

`h1` is a block level element. The divs `.appointments` come after it in your structure. You can set the `background-color` of the `h1` to the corresponding `.appointment` and remove the bottom `margin`, or you can simply nest the `h1` within `appointment`, as I have done in the snippet below.

```css
html,
body,
.calender {
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.appointmentsA {
  background: blue;
}

.appointmentsB {
  background: red;
}

.calender {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  table-layout: fixed;
  padding: 10px 10px 0 10px;
}

.calender .row {
  display: table-cell;
  padding: 0 10px;
}

.appointments {
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<main class="calender">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="appointments appointmentsA">
      <h1 class="title">ABC</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="appointments appointmentsB">
      <h1 class="title">DEF</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
</main>
```

Comment: I don't want to color everything, I changed my example with the calc function.

Comment: @Mr.Tr33 Can you provide an image of how the desired outcome should look? Thanks